# VBA Phantom Empty Array Value

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am looping through some data (only 8 values) in an Excel range from VBA, but I seem to be getting a 'phantom' empty array value in the middle.

Here is how I build the array. The range that it loops through results in 2 values being found, i.e. 2 values = 'rad'.

```
' arRoPtsXY is a 2D array
counter2 = UBound(arRoPtsXY, 2)
Dim arSecPtCt()
loopCtr = 0

For i = 1 To counter2
  rad = Sqr((secCX - arRoPtsXY(1, i)) ^ 2 + (secCY - arRoPtsXY(2, i)) ^ 2)
  If rad = secR Then
     ReDim Preserve arSecPtCt(i)
     arSecPtCt(loopCtr) = i
     loopCtr = loopCtr + 1
  End If
Next i
```

But when I perform this:

```
For a = LBound(arSecPtCt) To UBound(arSecPtCt)
  Debug.Print arSecPtCt(a)
Next a
```

I get this output:

```
1 
3 


'end
```

Note, above, there are 2 blank spaces being output (after 3, I added `'end` to show the spaces here), like the array 'space' exists, but it is empty.

If I do a `debug.print UBound(arSecPtCt)` I get '3', meaning 0,1,2,3 occupied array 'spaces'.

I just want my array to be:

```
1
3
```

As it is only the 1st and 3rd value that = 'rad'.

If I `debug.print i` during the if loop, it only outputs the 1 and 3, no spaces, so the loop seems to work, but I am just getting these extra blanks.

Hope someone can put me out my misery.

Many thanks in advance.

Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
ReDim Preserve arSecPtCt(i)
```

to

```
ReDim Preserve arSecPtCt(loopCtr)
```

Comment: Sigh...sometimes you just can't see the wood for trees :) Thought it would be something incredibly simple that I was overlooking. Thanks so much @RonRosenfeld